# Is the Owncloud password secure against brute force attack?

Tags: security, brute-force, owncloud

I'm using owncloud as my personal cloud storage, at home.
I read "Brute force attacks on passwords are guaranteed to succeed" from [Brute Force Attack[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack#Brute_Force).

Is it true? Any one who can brute force attack, can access my data on owncloud server?
I mean the login password on mobile or webserver page.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force attack will always succeed. But depending on your password it may take thousands or millions of years.

A brute force attack just tries every possible combination of password and hopes to guess the correct one. You may reduce the risk of the attacker guessing your password by using a long, complex one. Also you might be able to configure owncloud in such a way that it makes the brute force attack even more difficult. For example, let the user wait 10 minutes after 3 failed login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The key is that brute force attacks take a LONG time on well chosen and a properly stored password.  It *should* take years.

Online services generally throttle the number of attempts allowed per minute to make this sort of attack impractical.

Badly chosen passwords and/or poor storage mechanisms may reduce the effectiveness of such limits.

This is one reason for changing you password on some interval.  If the password storage were compromised and a brute force attack (or more likely one of several more efficient methods) to determine you password were underway, changing your password resets the clock.

Answer (score 0):

an update:

Currently an option to "prevent" brute force attacks has been added to the backlog (as an app) in March 2017: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/27507

Until then, options like fail2ban can be implemented manually. Here's one of the many how-tos: https://blog.monotok.org/prevent-brute-force-attacks-against-owncloud/

The whole issue hast been discussed in the past by the developers through github: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/1580

Cheers!